# Cocos2D/Math - clean angle conversion

Tags: math, cocos2d-iphone

Mornin' SO!

I'm just trying to hone my math-fu, and I have some questions regarding Cocos2D in particular. Since Cocos2D wants to 'simplify' things, all sprites have a rotation property, ranging from 0-360 (359?) CW. This forces you to do some rather (for me) mind-humping conversions when dealing with functions like atan.

So f.ex. this method:

```
- (void)rotateTowardsPoint:(CGPoint)point
{    
    // vector from me to the point
    CGPoint v = ccpSub(self.position, point);

    // ccpToAngle is just a cute wrapper for atan2f
    // the macro is self explanatory and the - is to flip the direction I guess
    float angle = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(ccpToAngle(v));

    // just to get it all in the range of 0-360
    if(angle < 0.f)
        angle += 360.0f;

    // but since '0' means east in Cocos..
    angle += 180.0f;

    // get us in the range of 0-360 again
    if(angle > 360.0f)
        angle -= 360.0f;

    self.rotation = angle;
}
```

works as intended. But to me it looks kind of brute forced. **Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same effect?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to do

```
float angle = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(ccpToAngle(v));
self.rotation = angle + 180.0f;
```

for equivalent transformations

Comment: Indeed! Just a weeee bit cleaner than my nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

```
// vector from me to the point
    CGPoint v = ccpSub(self.position, point);
```

actually, that's vector from point to you.

```
// just to get it all in the range of 0-360
```

you don't need to do that.

Comment: "actually, that's vector from point to you."
Yeah, come to think of it it certainly is. I totally knew that, I was just struck with morning-stupidity. Thank your for your reply!